# How can i initialize WebDriver's reference variable?

Tags: java, webdriver

I m using java.I m getting problem in setting the value.

```
//In some class
SeleniumBrowser webBrowser = new SeleniumBrowser();
WebDriver webDriver =null 
webBrowser.setWebDriver(webDriver);
```

initialization of webDriver to null is giving me error.

```
//In SeleniumBrowser class
public SeleniumBrowser implements BrowserInterface { 

public void setWebDriver(WebDriver webDriver) {
  this.webDriver = (Selenium) webDriver;
 }
}
```

how can i initialise webdriver to set it to the SeleniumBrowser object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use Firefox:

```
WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

IE:

```
WebDriver webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

HtmlUnit:

```
WebDriver webDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```

See these links for examples and more info:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/09_webdriver.html